# The attempt to mount a file system with type vfat in SCSI (0,0,0), partition #1 (sda) at /boot/eft failed

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, mount, uefi

Trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my Dell Vostro 3580 in an external drive(Pendrive) , it already has Windows 11 on a M.2 SSD whenever I try to install Ubuntu or Zorian on it , it gives me the following error!-
The attempt to mount a file system with type vfat in SCSI (0,0,0), partition #1 (sda) at /boot/eft failed.

How can I solve this ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOw43.jpg)

Comment: To be clear Windows is installed on a USB drive and you want to install Ubuntu to that same USB drive? vfat is more commonly known as Fat 32. Most Linux distros, including Ubuntu, default to using EXT4. Linux can mount FAT32 or NTFS as data disks; they cannot be used as the system disk.

Comment: If mounting during install like I do, you have to unmount the default ESP, and then mount the desired ESP which must be FAT32 with boot,esp flags. I find I have to mount at the screen where you enter password for it to have default mounted an ESP. Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #55 or( #23 & #26)
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 But this may be easier: https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator